# Add wordpress email/password to new table

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Wordpress user data (email, password , ...) stores in `wp_users` table.

I want to create a new table in my wordpress database and insert users email and password in my new table.

How can I do that?

Comment: To be used instead of wp_users? why?

Comment: @RRikesh I want to have my users data in another table. because I want to create a php forum on subdomain and use wordpress users data to login into my php forum

Comment: I believe you're attempting to find the [wrong solution to your problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 0):

this is the wrong solution and you will have issues with WordPress database updates in future. I think you can make rest API for authenticating forum users from main Wordpress site.